# Can anyone explain Wien's distribution law

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation

I searched the internet for this but could find only the equation associated with the law.
I want to know what this law states, what are its significance and why is it called as "distribution" law.

Comment: Well, it is about the where the peak is in the blackbody spectrum (which is distributed across wavelengths). You can get at it from Planck's blackbody equation. Nothing special.

Comment: Are you sure you mean [Wien's distribution law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_approximation) and not [Wien's displacement law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law). The former was a failed attempt to describe the black body spectrum. The latter relates the peak of the black body spectrum to the temperature.